# Alternate for minus in hive

Tags: hive

Can someone clearly explain to me how the below query works as an alternate for minus query in hive?

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
where Orders.CustomerID is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Minus = present in first and not present in second(in your case, Customer ID present in Customer not in Order)**

Please see below the explanation of your query.

Suppose customer table has the following data :

```
SNo,CustomerID
1,Customer1
2,Customer2
3,Customer3
```

Orders table has the following data:

```
SNo,CustomerID
1,Customer1
2,Customer3
3,Customer4
```

Subtracting Orders from Customer will give Customer2 as output.

Now when we are performing left join then it will take all the customer IDs from Customer table and join with Customer ID in orders table. When the 
Customer ID is present in Customer but not present in Order then it would be Null which you are selecting in your WHERE clause. See below the joining Output and based on your query you will get "Customer2,Null" as your output.

```
Joining Output :
Customer1,Customer1
Customer2,Null
Customer3,Customer3
```